# C++ do while loop menu

Tags: c++

I have wrote a program to insert student names and displaying the list once name have inserted.The problem I am having is with the menu. When I input 1st value, message of system exiting displays. It's my first time writing a program for data structures and I am not familiar with the concepts. If you could correct me with where I went wrong will be helpful. Appreciate your response as I am stuck with this. See source code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    string studentname;
    node* next;
};
bool isempty(node* head);
char menu();
void insertFirstElement(node*& head, node*& last, string studentname);
void insert(node *&head, node *&last, string studentname);
void remove(node*& head, node *&last);
void showlist(node* current);
int main()
{
    node* head = NULL;
    node* last = NULL;
    char choice;
    string name;

    do {
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Please enter a student name : ";
            cin >> name;
            insert(head, last, name);
            break;
        case 2:
            remove(head, last);
            break;
        case 3:
            showlist(head);
            break;
        default :
            cout << "System is exiting" << endl;

        }
    } while (choice != 4);
}
bool isempty(node* head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return true;
    else
    return false;
}
char menu()
{
    char choice;
    cout << "1. Add a element" << endl;
    cout << "2. Remove an element" << endl;
    cout << "3. Display list" << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit" << endl;

    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}
void insertFirstElement(node*& head, node*& last, string studentname)
{
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->studentname = studentname;
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    last = temp;
}
void insert(node*& head, node*& last, string studentname)
{
    if (isempty(head)) {
        insertFirstElement(head, last, studentname);
    }
    else {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->studentname = studentname;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}
void remove(node*& head, node*& last)
{
    if (isempty(head)) {
        cout << "The list is already empty" << endl;
    }
    else if (head == last) {
        delete head;
        head == NULL;
        last == NULL;
   }
    else {
        node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
void showlist(node* current)
{
    if (isempty(current)) {
        cout << "The list is empty" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The list containts: \n";
        while (current != NULL) {
            cout << current->studentname << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: There is no known encoding where `'1' == 1`. Characters and integers are different. The `menu` function reads and return characters, your `switch` and loop condition uses integers.

Answer (score 0):

your choice variable is of type char and your function is returning a char, therefor your while condition should be

```
while (choice != '4');
```

or you can change your function to type int and your variable to type int.

also you should be using NULLPTR instead of NULL

Comment: Thanks. Have one quick question to ask. Is my getline statement wrong? it doesn't allow me to input the name. If you could reply will be helpful to me.                                                                       
  node* head = nullptr;
    node* last = nullptr;

    int choice;
    string name;
    
    do {
        choice = menu();

        switch (choice) {
        case '1':
            cout << "Please enter a student name : ";
            getline(cin, name);
            insert(head, last, name);
            break;

Comment: that is how you would normally use getline
eg
getline(cin,name);
cout << name;

after your getline cout name and see if there is an output, if there is the problem would most likely be in your insert function.
also if my answer helped dont forget to mark as correct